# Angular-Cli from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular-cli, spawn

Building my project using Angular-Cli works when I use it directly from my terminal window like this:

`$ ng build`

Now I'd like to run it from `nodejs` using spawn. However,

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const bld = spawn("ng build");
```

throws:

```
child process has an error with code Error: spawn ng build ENOENT
child process exited with code -2
```

Why is this happening? (I am running everything from inside the same folder.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) doesn't behave like a command line.

You send the command and args separately like:

```
spawn('ng', ['build'])
```

In your case it tried to do `ng\ build` and can not find that file.